# AngularJS is breaking the routing url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with Angular JS,

When accessing this:

> domain.name/#/filme/view/Dilwale/524

It is changing the url to this:

> domain.name/#!/#%2Ffilme%2Fview%2FDilwale%2F524

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: If you build a demo app it will be easier to help you. At least put some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my answer: [Why is there #! in the url of my angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121088/why-is-there-in-the-url-of-my-angular-app/41121698#41121698)

It also could be because of breaking changes in angular 1.6.0. (if you are using angular 1.6.0 :)

changelog: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

change: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52

BREAKING CHANGE

> The hash-prefix for $location hash-bang URLs has changed from the
>   empty string "" to the bang "!". If your application does not use
>   HTML5 mode or is being run on browsers that do not support HTML5 mode,
>   and you have not specified your own hash-prefix then client side URLs
>   will now contain a "!" prefix. For example, rather than
>   mydomain.com/#/a/b/c will become mydomain/#!/a/b/c.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem.

Comment: what about the rest of the url?

Comment: 2F is ascii for /. What does your link(href) to that route look like? Is it '#/films' by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of encoding is done for your URL :

```
domain.name/#/filme/view/Dilwale/524
```

Look at the below screenshot
[image]

To verify use this [LINK](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/)

Comment: Yes, but i am not encoding it, and i didnt set angular to encode it, why this happens/?

Comment: you will not ask angular to encode! but ur browser does it for u.

Comment: it does it for me, but angular does not work with encoded url :D

Comment: Don't use strange characters in the URL

Comment: There is no strange characters in my url, it is the one in the main message, but it hashes even the dashes.